# How to get subtotals for a dynamic column value in SQL?

Tags: sql, group-by

[image]

In the image you see 5 columns.

The problem is that Total only needs to count from the Column 'User Type Name'

Then it also only needs to take 1 top row each ID.

So, for the 'Hosted Exchange Basic' the total should be 1 and 90 and 'Terminal Server User' 1 and 50.

Comment: Don't post sample data as links to somewhere else. Add the examples as formatted text (not as a screenshot) to your question. Ideally using `insert` statements or setup a http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: I assume this is SSRS?

Comment: Yes, and there are multiple tables

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [First](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms159861(v=sql.100).aspx) Function as your textbox expression for the MB Used Total.

`=First(Fields![MBUsed].Value, "[DataSetName]")`

Your Total underneath the account name should look like this:

`=(Fields.[IDColumn.Value] , "[DataSetName]")`

Changing the [IDColumn] to the column name.
In both expressions, you can omit the `, "[DataSetName]"` so long as your report only contains a single dataset.